# No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'. context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, arguments

**when I try to run flutter projects it throw these errors and other errors as well can anyone help me out**

[image: Debug Console Image]

Comment: Which version of Flutter are you using? If you're using the beta version that has null-safety enabled, the `nullOk` parameter was removed from `Localizations.localeOf`.  Otherwise you'll need to stick with the stable version (1.22.6 as of writing).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix this nullOk error when using the flutter_svg package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66144283/how-to-fix-the-error-when-connecting-the-flutter-svg-package-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 52):

Try updating your `flutter_svg` package to this pre-release version.

`flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3`

Comment: Thanks, this should be marked as right answer

Comment: @Tyler Hi, I have not used flutter_svg in my project then also getting this error. Can you give me solution?

Comment: @ShriyaPandya I would check over your dependencies in pubspec.yaml and try and update to null safety for all your dependencies.  You might also have to `flutter clean` if you change versions.