# How to fix this nullOk error when using the flutter_svg package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I connected the package, added it to main.dart, I try to compile the application, but I get this error. Help! What should I do about it?

error

```html
Launching lib\main.dart on XT1562 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/D:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.18.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:50:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
        context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
                                                          ^^^^^^
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
                ^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Which Flutter channel do you work on?

Comment: I use master channel

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Follow the steps below

1. add the following dependency

```
  flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3
```

2. run `flutter clean` command
3. run `flutter pub get` command
4. run `flutter run` command or run the project

Comment: Thanks, @prahack, was facing this for a week on CodeMagic Pipelines.

Answer (score 19):

Everyone is right: putting `flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3` or `flutter_svg: ^0.19.3` (in case you can't migrate to null safety yet) is the solution.
I want to add a little thing: if you're using a package which depends on flutter_svg and you still get the error due to older versions usage, you can fix it in this way:

```
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
```

I lost plenty of time because the `flags: ^3.2.2` package was using `flutter_svg: ^0.19.1` and it led to the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the version of Flutter with null-safety enabled (currently on the beta channel as of writing), the `nullOk` parameter was removed `Localizations.localeOf`, but you're using a package (in this case, `flutter_svg`) that is still using `nullOk`.

If you're using the null-safe version of Flutter, you should use null-safe versions of other packages too, if available.  Alternatively you can stick with the latest version of Flutter without null-safety (version 1.22.x) until all of your dependent packages have been migrated for null-safety.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem . After I finally got the solution.
Here Simple:

At first you add Pre-Release the following dependency:

```
flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3
```

Then run `flutter pub get` command

Now you can run your project . See that there is no error .

Answer (score 0):

On line 57 of the locally cached file `/lib/src/picture_provider.dart` (see the full path from the  error message)replace
`Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true)`, with `Localizations.maybeLocaleOf(context)`

This is quick and dirty solution, but should hold until the package is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you want to fix this error for yourself or for a package that you are using, you can fix it the following way

> In order to modify your code to use the new form of the APIs, convert all instances of calls that include nullOk = true as a parameter to use the maybe form of the API instead.

```dart
MediaQueryData? data = MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true);
```

becomes

```dart
MediaQueryData? data = MediaQuery.maybeOf(context);
```

[More about how to migrate towards null-safety in the official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/eliminating-nullok-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything, in vain.

Finally, the updating a dependency worked for me.

This is what I updated in my pubspec.yaml file:

Removed

```
flutter_svg: ^0.18.0
```

and added

```
flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3
```

Then, ran

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

simply go into the file in .pub-cache and correct the argument from localeOf(context, nullOk: true) to localeOf(context)

Comment: You should never change code in the .pub-cache. Changes will get lost after the next `pub get`.