# Error comes when I run my app on android studio cloned from git hub

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I cloned an app from a git hub repo and when I ran it on my system, it shows this error.

```
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.19.3/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:56:45: Error: Method not found: 'Localizations.maybeLocaleOf'.
locale: context != null ? Localizations.maybeLocaleOf(context) : null,
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.19.3/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:57:53: Error: Method not found: 'Directionality.maybeOf'.
textDirection: context != null ? Directionality.maybeOf(context) : null,
                                                ^^^^^^^
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
*Where
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Here is the snap of the flutter doctor -v

[Flutter doctor console snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5ccJ.png)

It keeps showing this error that flutter and dart plugins are not installed. If you could also provide a solution to that or is it that there is some issue with the latest version of flutter?

Please if someone could help!

Answer (score 0):

The error in flutter doctor is normal, everything works despite those two errors.
Did you run `flutter pub get` after cloning your project?

The error is also specifically telling you to go to the file: 'lib/src/picture_provider.dart'
then go to line #57 and in column 53 there is that error. It might be an outdated package or something incompatible with null-safety.

[take a look at this similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66144283/how-to-fix-this-nullok-error-when-using-the-flutter-svg-package)